# Edit inlinechangelink in admin.TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

I am struggling to access and edit the inlinechangelink in a specific inline:
[image: Inline Edit Button]

Any idea how I can access/edit this via the admin.TabularInline or template?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you trying to change this to? What is the link pointing to in the first place? What is "Antragmitarbeiter" in the admin? What's the field that has that link? show us the model and show us the relevant admin code.

Comment: The link will point to the admin change page for that model object. If you want to change it, you probably want it to point outside of the Django admin? In that case you might want to turn the auto linking off (using has_change_permission False maybe) and add your custom link field in the inline model using format_html() to return the link.

Comment: @Risadinha You are correct. It's the change_link in a django admin TabularInline to the referenced model object. I want to stay inside django and link to a different model object. But your solution with a custom column populated with a format_html() would work, too! I was just searching for a more elegant way to edit the change_link itself within the admin.TabularInline in the admin.py. I'll try your suggested solution. Thanks!